# What programming language and technology used to make this game?

Tags: sockets, browser

What programming language and technology used to make the game at this page:

http://www.mundijuegos.com/juegos/juego.php?juego=7&sala=13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They use Flash, in general you have just to righ click and see if in the popup menu you have Flash or not, and in general the majority of web games are developed in Flash or Flex.